# Refreshing ListView data after setting Preferences double populates

Tags: java, android

I'm a Java and Android newbie. I'm creating something that requires a listview. The listview data is calculated from GPS coordinates which are set in a preferences window. My problem is that after I enter in new coordinates, the listview data does'nt reflect this.

What have I tried so far? I've watched the Google I/O 2010 video and am using notifyDataSetChanged() during onResume().

However when I do this, the listview and its header are populated two times. What am I doing wrong? Sections of the code follow

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
GPSTracker gps;
Date yetzt = new Date();    
String locationName = "";
double latitude = 0;
double longitude = 0;
double elevation = 0;

List<RowItem> rowItems;
ListView listView;
String tmp = "";
ItemListViewAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();

    // check if GPS enabled
    if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
        showInfo();
    } else {
        // can't get location
        // GPS or Network is not enabled
        // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
        gps.showSettingsAlert();
    }
}

private void showInfo() {       
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();        
    locationName = tz.getDisplayName(false, TimeZone.SHORT);
    latitude = Float.parseFloat(sharedPrefs.getString("manual_fetch_lat", Double.toString(gps.getLatitude())));
    longitude = Float.parseFloat(sharedPrefs.getString("manual_fetch_long", Double.toString(gps.getLongitude())));      
    TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone(tz.getID());       

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    //add stuff into rowItems here
    adapter = new ItemListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.listview_item_row, rowItems);

    View header = (View)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listview_header_row, null);

    TextView t = new TextView(this);
    t = (TextView)header.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    if ( t != null ) {
        t.setText("Demo");
    }

    listView.addHeaderView(header);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, 0, 0, R.string.preference_menu_title);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case 0:
        startActivity(new Intent(this, EditSettingsActivity.class));
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

My ListViewAdapter is as follows

```
public class ItemListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RowItem> {
private Context context;

public ItemListViewAdapter(Context context, int resource,
        List<RowItem> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    this.context = context;
}

/* private view holder class */
private class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView txtTitle;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    RowItem rowItem = getItem(position);

    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item_row, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    holder.txtTitle.setText(rowItem.getTitle());
    holder.imageView.setImageResource(rowItem.getImageId());

    return convertView;
}
```

}

ListView data is populated as shown

```
        GeoLocation location = new GeoLocation(locationName, latitude, longitude, elevation, timeZone);
    ComplexZmanimCalendar czc = new ComplexZmanimCalendar(location);
    ComplexZmanimCalendar czcPrevious = new ComplexZmanimCalendar(location);
    ComplexZmanimCalendar czcNight = new ComplexZmanimCalendar(location);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();      

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Section 1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    //subtract one day from current date
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
    czcPrevious.setCalendar(cal);
    diff = czcPrevious.getSunset().getTime() - czcPrevious.getSunrise().getTime();
    interval = diff/12;

    SimpleDateFormat parserSDF=new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");   
    List<String> x = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(int counter=0; counter < 12; counter++){    


        tmp = "From "+ parserSDF.format(new Date(czcPrevious.getSunrise().getTime() + (counter*interval) ))+" to "+parserSDF.format(new Date(czcPrevious.getSunrise().getTime() + ((counter+1)*interval) ));
        n = getResources().getIdentifier(logo[counter].toLowerCase(),"drawable", getPackageName());
        item = new RowItem(n, tmp);
        rowItems.add(item);                 
    }       

    diff = czc.getSunrise().getTime() - czcPrevious.getSunset().getTime();
    interval = diff/12;

    for(int counter=0; counter < 12; counter++){                

        tmp = "From "+ parserSDF.format(new Date(czcPrevious.getSunset().getTime() + (counter*interval) ))+" to "+parserSDF.format(new Date(czcPrevious.getSunset().getTime() + ((counter+1)*interval) ));
        n = getResources().getIdentifier(logo[counter].toLowerCase(),"drawable", getPackageName());
        item = new RowItem(n, tmp);
        rowItems.add(item);             

    }
```

Comment: Please post your "ItemListViewAdapter".

Comment: @larry-mckenzie Done. See the very end of the code

Comment: You have a comment where you set "rowItems" can you please fill that in.

Comment: @larry-mckenzie Done. See end of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont see any place where you modify or populate your array "rowItems" with any values.

Can you post the EditSettingsActivity so we can see what you do in there?

So far you can change this lines of code:

```
TextView t = new TextView(this);
t = (TextView)header.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

...for this one...

```
TextView t = (TextView)header.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

I have just seen your adapter and is almost perfect, I can see you follow the google video of google I/O , XD.... just make your adapter...

```
static class ViewHolder {
```

EditSettingsActivity would help to understand the life cycle of your app...but for now...

If your MainActivity depends of some values that you set on EditSettingsActivity, then you have to return the values to the MainActivity to modify the array rowItems declared on MainActivity and after you modify this array then you can call notifyDataSetChanged().

You could do this with startActivityForResult and you can find here how it works:

aryo.info/blog/android-returning-value-to-the-calling.html

I dont know what type of values you are modifying on EditSettingsActivity but you also have the possibility to store them on SharePreferences and retrieve them on your MainActivity when you come back.
This way the next time the user access to the app, he keeps the same preferences that he set the last time and only if you uninstall the app they will be removed.

How to use shared preferences:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

I have just added and example project in this link that does exactly what you want and it is working:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33565803/StackOverFlowExamples/ListViewHeaderAddItemsNotifyDataExample.zip

Comment: Are you calling a function where the comment was that does all this? How do you modify your list later depending what the user do in settings?

Comment: I use shared preferences in my MainActivity. I use the EditSettingsActivity to allow users to manually enter GPS coordinates. These are then used in the MainActivity. Please have a look at the first 6 lines of showinfo().

Comment: My problem is that if I call showinfo() and then notifyDataSetChanged() the lisview populates twice i.e there are two headers and identical rows in the ListView

Comment: I have just added and example project in this link that does exactly what you want and it is working:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33565803/ListViewHeaderAddItemsNotifyDataExample.zip

Comment: Let me know if you have any problem, I put the line of notifyDataSetChanged() on onResume  (in my code it would be necessary) as well to show you that it was not populating the list again, the only thing it does is reflect the changes on the list if the array has any.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32163/discussion-between-user1801060-and-jpardogo)

Comment: Thanks a lot for you help. Was able to refresh the data. Each time the activity refreshes, it has an extra header, but I will post that as a different question.

Comment: How are you getting an extra header? you are executing two times listView.addHeaderView(header) ? Can you post all places from where you call the function that has this line?

Comment: I call the function showinfo() during onCreate() and again during onResume(). those are the only two places where I add a header

Comment: Do it only on onResume() otherwise you are calling two times at start (onCreate() and in onResume())and adding two headers.

Anyway I dont know if populate the list each time you come back to the activity is the best idea. 

I would work with fragments and I would use interfaces to comunicate with the activity when the user change the preferences, and through this interface  call the functions that populate again the array and call notifyDataSetChanged().

If you dont wanna go into fragments just check the activities life cycle:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html